# Create a generic Dialog method with Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, dialog

I would like to create a generic method to create a specific dialog.

```
private void setDialog(String dialog,String title){
    try {
        // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/view/" + dialog + ".fxml"));
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setTitle(title);
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(Main.getPs());
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        dialogStage.setScene(scene);


     loader.getController().setDialogStage(dialogStage);

        // Show the dialog and wait until the user closes it
        dialogStage.showAndWait();


      } catch (IOException e) {
        // Exception gets thrown if the fxml file could not be loaded
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

}
```

But I get an error in this line

```
loader.getController().setDialogStage(dialogStage)
```

exactly the mistake is this

```
"The method setDialogStage(Stage) is undefined for the type Object"
```

how do I fix it? thank you.

I'm not very experienced. that says that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some controller class `MyController` that defines a `setDialogStage(Stage)` method, you can do

```
loader.<MyController>getController().setDialogStage(dialogStage);
```

This isn't really any more typesafe than a simple cast; it will fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException` if the controller is not the correct type.

If you have multiple controllers that may have this method, the best option is probably to make them implement an interface that defines the relevant method:

```
public interface DialogController {

    public void setDialogStage(Stage dialogStage);

}
```

Your controllers look like

```
public class MyController implements DialogController {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void setDialogStage(Stage dialogStage) {
         // ...
    }

}
```

and then you just treat the controller as a general `DialogController`:

```
loader.<DialogController>getController().setDialogStage(dialogStage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you may have good reasons to create your own dialog mechanism, I would like to point out that JavaFX already has a [standard way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) for dialogs.

The website [code.makery](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) shows some examples of how to create dialogs:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
alert.setHeaderText("Look, a Confirmation Dialog");
alert.setContentText("Are you ok with this?");

Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
    // ... user chose OK
} else {
    // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
}
```

[image: Confirmation dialog]

You can also create dialogs with a custom content:
[image: Exception Dialog]